# DPDK: unable to ping DPDK-kni-captured NIC port

Tags: dpdk

I followed the instructions [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-20.11/sample_app_ug/kernel_nic_interface.html) to run the KNI sample application with DPDK v20.11.8. And I cannot successfully perform a remote ping.

The NIC status is shown below. Remote ping 10.11.140.8 is successful.

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.11.140.8  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.11.143.255
        inet6 fe80::ea61:1fff:????:????  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e8:61:1f:??:??:??  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1652015  bytes 119549045 (119.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 661719  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18400  bytes 951902 (951.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Firstly I bind `enp3s0` to `uio_pci_generic` driver and load `rte_kni` module with carrier=off.

```
???@??????:~/dpdk-stable-20.11.8/usertools$ dpdk-devbind.py  --status

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:03:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=igb,vfio-pci

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
......
```

```
???@??????:~/dpdk-stable-20.11.8/build/kernel/linux/kni$ sudo rmmod rte_kni
[sudo] password for ???:
???@??????:~/dpdk-stable-20.11.8/build/kernel/linux/kni$ sudo insmod rte_kni.ko carrier=off
???@??????:~/dpdk-stable-20.11.8/build/kernel/linux/kni$ cd ../../../examples
???@??????:~/dpdk-stable-20.11.8/build/examples$ sudo ./dpdk-kni  -l 4-7 -n 4 -- -P -p 0x1 --config="(0,4,6,8)"
```

Then I run the sample application and it seems to be OK.

```
EAL: Detected 16 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_igb (8086:1533) device: 0000:03:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
APP: Initialising port 0 ...
Port 0, MAC address: E8:61:1F:??:??:??


Checking link status
............................done
Port 0 Link up at 1 Gbps FDX Autoneg
APP: ========================
APP: KNI Running
APP: kill -SIGUSR1 243150
APP:     Show KNI Statistics.
APP: kill -SIGUSR2 243150
APP:     Zero KNI Statistics.
APP: ========================
APP: Lcore 5 has nothing to do
APP: Lcore 6 is writing to port 0
APP: Lcore 4 is reading from port 0
APP: Lcore 7 has nothing to do
```

Finally, IP, netmask and gw are added to the veth0_0:

```
sudo ifconfig vEth0_0 10.11.140.8 netmask 255.255.252.0
```

ifconfig shows:

```
vEth0_0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.11.140.8  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.11.143.255
        ether e8:61:1f:??:??:??  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ip addr shows:

```
vEth0_0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:61:1f:??:??:?? brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.11.140.8/22 brd 10.11.143.255 scope global vEth0_0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The veth is up but it is not running, and
**we cannot perform a remote ping to 10.11.140.8**.

My question are as follows:

1. What else need to be configured to make sure that we could remote ping the DPDK-captured NIC?
2. Is it possible to set the IP of DPDK-captured NIC? I found that MAC\MTU\IP could be configured through KNI, but I do not find the method to configure IP on the DPDK-captured physical NIC.